# Original Mariner 4 data values

Tags: mars, space-art, raw-data, education

Scott Manley recently did a video where he shows how the first [image of Mars from up close](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_4) was done with pastels while the impatient engineers [waited for the image processing department to finish their work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSQlM6yGh7k).

I would love to print these strips and do the paint-by-number with my children. **Does anybody know from where one could acquire the original Mariner 4 data values?**

Comment: related: [Do you recognize these space artists who made this (possibly) first "paint-by-numbers" image of Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26525/12102)  Dan Goods is mentioned there, and is now mentioned in [this answer to *Was the Orbit Pavilion triggered by real communications events?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61228/12102)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-mariner 9 data, I believe, are not publicly available. In NASA PDS (https://atmos.nmsu.edu/data_and_services/atmospheres_data/MARS/mars_orbiter.html), it is written that we can only search for Mariner 4, 6, and 7 publications but it isn't written anywhere about the availability of the datasets. So, if you really want the data, I would suggest you to mail NASA PDS and see if they can provide the data or not.

Comment: Mariner 6 and 7 images are available in a [PDS bundle](https://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/mariner/duxbury_mariner69.htm) at the PDS Geosciences Node but this doesn't help the OP with finding Mariner 4 data

Comment: Thank you. You've pointed me in the correct direction, I've emailed the contact on the PDS website.